# Jquery datepicker to Input normal text and Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How can I use the jquery datepicker to input date from an icon and also to take random text from keyboard.

For example
I need a text box to take Exact date (26-10-2015) and also text like since 3 years.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which datepicker plugin are you using? Provide relevant info in question itself

Comment: Now i am using jquery datepicker but This plugin prevents the random text @A.Wolff

Comment: i tried to do it manually by using cal Icon reference to textbox but failed @Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a hidden input as datepicker with this kind of logic e.g:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "https://htmlcssphptutorial.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/b_calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date",
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      $(this).prev().val(dateText);
    }
  });
  $('input + .date').prev().on('change', function() {
    var dateStr = this.value.split(/[\/-]/);
     $(this).next().datepicker("setDate", new Date(dateStr[2], dateStr[1] - 1, dateStr[0]) );
  })
});
```

```css
.date {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Any text there" />
<input type="text" name="date" class="date" readonly />
```